# Adding window.event handler to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Normally when I wanted to catch an event on a page in js:

```
window.onkeydown = function (event) {
    //Do something here
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out (or Google) how to do this in typescript. For the setup I am working in, there is a `ts` file for the page, and a `ts` file for the class that it is loading.

Comment: Do you have an alternative, like `window.addEventListener`?

Comment: If there is something that accomplishes the above, for typescript, then it is an alternative

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the environment? Are you compiling the code to run on a browser or interpreting somewhere?

Comment: It is a MVC project

Comment: What's the problem ? this code both compiles and work.

Comment: I need this to be inside of a typescript file. I do not know how to write event handlers in typescript for a page. The event handler needs access to variables and functions within a typescript class

Comment: @MikeViscontini what's the compile error you get for the code above or problem you're having though? Can you show an example that doesn't work? This code should compile as AlexG said (though using addEventListener is better).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownListener, false)
```

`window` is defined will all events in `lib.d.ts` and this particular listener as

```
 addEventListener(type: "keydown", listener: (ev: KeyboardEvent) => any, useCapture?: boolean): void;
```

or this, if you want to keep your original "style",

```
window.onkeydown = (ev: KeyboardEvent): any => {
     //do something
}
```

Comment: There is no need for this if your project is setup correctly.

lib.d.ts defines window with an onkeydown property.

Answer (score 3):

To answer more clearly:

```
const controlDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    console.log(event);
};
window.addEventListener('keydown', controlDown);
```

Comment: Get `Type '(event: React.KeyboardEvent<Element>) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.`

Comment: In case of using this with React make sure you don't accidentally use `import { KeyboardEvent } from "react";`. This leads to the `not assignable to type 'EventListener'` exception. Instead the KeyboardEvent from globalThis must be used (i.e. simply remove the import statement)

Answer (score 2):

```
windows.addEventListener('keydown', (event: KeyboardEvent) =>{
 // if you need event.code
});

windows.addEventListener('keydown', (event: Event) =>{
 // event
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you're using Typescript in React**, just remove the `import { KeyboardEvent } from "react"` and use the global `KeyboardEvent` type without import it from anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you'r using working in nextJs 14. Instead of KeyboardEvent try,
globalThis.KeyboardEvent.

```
const yourFunc = (ev: globalThis.KeyboardEvent):any => {
// you code
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", youFunc);
```