# Display and Select Bounding Boxes on Image

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Given coordinates for bounding boxes and an image, I would like to display clickable bounding boxes over the image in an Angular Web Application.

The goal is that the user should select one or multiple bounding boxes drawn over the image for labelling purposes.

So far I have only seen drawable bounding boxes with HTML Canvas. However, in my case, multiple bounding boxes already exist. How could I approach this task?

EDIT: I have tried layering two canvas elements on top of each other, however, I could not even get the image to display, let alone make rectangles appear.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvnjc3

component.html:

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
 <canvas #layer1 id="layer1" width={{imgWidth}} height={{imgHeight}} 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
 <canvas #layer2 id="layer2" width={{imgWidth}} height={{imgHeight}}
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```js
export class AppComponent {

  public imgWidth: number;
  public imgHeight: number;
  public url: string;
  public image;

  @ViewChild("layer1", { static: false }) layer1Canvas: ElementRef;
  private context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  private layer1CanvasElement: any;

  onSelectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

      reader.onload = event => {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = reader.result;
        this.image.onload = () => {
          this.imgWidth = this.image.width;
          this.imgHeight = this.image.height;
          this.showImage();
        };
      };
    }
  }

  showImage() {
    this.layer1CanvasElement = this.layer1Canvas.nativeElement;
    this.context = this.layer1CanvasElement.getContext("2d");
    this.context.drawImage(this.image, this.imgWidth, this.imgHeight);
    this.drawRect();
  }

  drawRect() {
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.rect(200, 300, 400, 500);
    this.context.lineWidth = 10;
    this.context.strokeStyle = "black";
    this.context.stroke();
  }
}
```

Comment: add the code you tried and try creating a demo on stackblitz

Comment: Thank you, I should have done that before. Did some more research and tried my best until I got stuck; added a stackblitz demo and the relevant code here.

Comment: Did answer solve your problem ? If it did, can you share the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Stackblitz Link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lg4lmy

### Preview

[image]

### Step 01

- remove

  ```
  width={{imgWidth}} height={{imgHeight}}
  ```

### Step 02

- add

  ```
  this.layer1CanvasElement.width = this.imgWidth;
  this.layer1CanvasElement.height = this.imgHeight;
  ```

### Step 03

- change from

  ```
  this.context.drawImage(this.image,this.imgWidth, this.imgHeight);
  ```
- to

  ```
  this.context.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.imgWidth, this.imgHeight);
  ```

### Step 04

- add mousemove event listener

  ```
  this.layer1CanvasElement.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {})
  ```

### Step 05

- determine if the **Point**

  ```
    (PointX,PointY)
  ```
- belong to the **Rectangle**

  ```
    (RectangleX,RectangleY,RectangleWidth,RectangleHeight)
  ```
- by using

  ```
    (RectangleX <=       PointX       <= RectangleX + RectangleWidth)
    (RectangleY <=       PointY       <= RectangleY + RectangleHeight)
  ```
- code

  ```
    let x = 200;
    let y = 300;
    let w = 400;
    let h = 500;

    if ( 
         x <= e.clientX && e.clientX <= x + w 
                          &&
         y <= e.clientY && e.clientY <= y + h  
       )
       drawRect("red");
       else 
       drawRect("black");
  });
  ```

### Why Step 01 && 02

- no sure but i think it liked to angular change detection

### Why Step 03

- base on [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) you are misusing the overload

  > void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy);
  >
  > void ctx.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
  >
  > void ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);

### Why Step 04 && 05

- my understanding you needed to implement this feature

  > I would like to display clickable bounding boxes

### Ref. important

[HTMLCanvasElement.getContext() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext)

[CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

[Clickable canvas circle](https://codepen.io/DanielTate/pen/NGLRGg)

[Hit Region Detection For HTML5 Canvas And How To Listen To Click Events On Canvas Shapes](https://lavrton.com/hit-region-detection-for-html5-canvas-and-how-to-listen-to-click-events-on-canvas-shapes-815034d7e9f8/)

[MouseEvent.clientX - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX)

### Ref. unimportant

[getContext("2d");+ - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=getContext(%222d%22)%3B%2B&oq=getContext(%222d%22)%3B%2B&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.1969j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[What is my_canvas.getContext("2d"); and how it work? | Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/51aa52d9ca045d53fe00126b)

[access angular app from console - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=access+angular+app+from+console&oq=access+angular+app+from&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l7.17892j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[Debugging Angular from the Browser Console - Made by Munsters - Medium](https://medium.com/made-by-munsters/debugging-angular-from-the-browser-console-57b06ab3304c)

[js get image size from FileReader - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNSq3W3Ig2L-pO2hGGJlQjTodd57dQ%3A1575970961588&ei=kWjvXeu_I6S5gweSv4iABg&q=js+get+image+size+from+FileReader&oq=js+get+image+size+from+FileReader&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3j0i22i30l2j0i333.24828.39345..39573...1.2..0.476.7801.4-17......0....1j2..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i67j0i20i263j0i13.dAtuFjKKvkE&ved=0ahUKEwirzN2q5armAhWk3OAKHZIfAmAQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

[javascript - Getting width & height of an image with filereader - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491193/getting-width-height-of-an-image-with-filereader)

[jquery - Get the real width and height of an image with JavaScript? (in Safari/Chrome) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-the-real-width-and-height-of-an-image-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome)

[onload image angluer - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQr-zOp66bEVF86z2lAF1vGbT43rA%3A1575971102514&ei=HmnvXYuDH8XTgwfjoa2QAg&q=onload+image+angluer&oq=onload+image+angluer&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160l3.6089.7719..7818...0.2..0.528.2228.4-4j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0j0i67j0i20i263j0i22i30.ierhHLccnE4&ved=0ahUKEwiLivft5armAhXF6eAKHeNQCyIQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

[image.onload - Archive of obsolete content | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Attribute/image.onload)

[angular - Detect when image has loaded in img tag - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257687/detect-when-image-has-loaded-in-img-tag/39257902)

[angluer this.context.drawImage - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=angluer+this.context.drawImage&oq=angluer+this.context.drawImage&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j69i60l4j69i65j69i61.2534j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[typescript - Angular 5 with Canvas drawImage not showing up - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214548/angular-5-with-canvas-drawimage-not-showing-up)

[javascript - CanvasContext2D drawImage() issue [onload and CORS] - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880641/canvascontext2d-drawimage-issue-onload-and-cors)

[addeventlistener definition file typescript - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNRF8Au-JHFHIv1wqLEQW-vnv-CV2w%3A1575973980717&ei=XHTvXYGlK6iRlwSI1arYDA&q=addeventlistener+definition+file+typescript&oq=addeventlistener+definition+file+types&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.33i160.6135.11632..12928...1.5..0.612.2363.3-1j2j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j33i22i29i30.Wu9NHK64_ho)

[javascript - Adding window.event handler to typescript - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660518/adding-window-event-handler-to-typescript)

[clientX - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=clientX&oq=clientX&aqs=chrome..69i57.382j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[is poin Belongs to sqrae - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNTAmhedCQtdHtVh6z-PduOp7BkvZw%3A1575979594735&ei=SorvXcjALIfQaJGRh5gL&q=is+poin+Belongs+to++sqrae&oq=is+poin+Belongs+to++sqrae&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160.54892.62330..62492...2.5..0.482.2696.4-6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i304i39j0i13i5i30.fmzVUm0ylSw&ved=0ahUKEwjIjau_havmAhUHKBoKHZHIAbMQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

[analytic geometry - How to check if a point is inside a rectangle? - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle)

[Plane (geometry) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry))

[angular - Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45974764/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-types-boolean-and-number)

[stroke() - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=stroke()&oq=stroke()&aqs=chrome..69i57.294j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[HTML canvas stroke() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_stroke.asp)

[canvas change path color on hover - Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNTk29Vilajv2f0eP7Rn6hipe9zDwA%3A1575980563606&ei=E47vXa_LJMKua4j6t9AI&q=canvas+change+path+color+on+hover&oq=canvas+change+path+color+on+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.33i22i29i30l10.716.4314..5283...1.2..0.1047.3521.4-2j0j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i30.xoRzw7MzXb8)

[javascript - Change color lines in canvas when mouseover - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46543611/change-color-lines-in-canvas-when-mouseover)

Comment: Thank you so much, that has helped a lot.
I had to change from clientX/Y to offsetX/Y from the MouseMove Event, otherwise it would highlight the wrong boxes.
There is quite a big performance impact though, with a couple hundred bounding boxes there is significant load.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool named Annotorious. I have used it for annotating images in Angular 8. The tool is licensed under BSD License. Pretty easy to use. You could download the source code and edit the widgets if you want. Totally great tool.
[Annotorious tool](https://recogito.github.io/annotorious/)